# Drupal changes saved in git

Tags: git, drupal, web, repository

I'm doing some changes in a Drupal website and I was wondering that if I make some changes to the internal features in the website (such as blocks) then does these changes are saved in the git repository? I'm not touching any of the code.

Thank you

Comment: The git repository is only the source code (files) of your website. All your configuration (in administration) and content are database only. Code != content

Answer (score 3):

As Djouuuh said, configuration is not stored in code (for the most part) in Drupal. In a default Drupal install, changes to blocks are not stored in code.

However, you can use the Features module (https://www.drupal.org/project/features) combined with the Features Extra module (https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra) to put the block code into code that can be stored in a git repository. Following is from the Features Extra module project page re: blocks:

> To export a block, install FE Block, edit your block, give it a "machine name," export it with Features. You can export block settings (region settings, visibility settings, ...) of any block, and the content of blocks created with the Block module from Drupal core.
>   The D7 version supports the Block Class, i18n block and Block Cache Alter modules.